# git only tracking a single directory without any files

Tags: git

git status shows:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        common/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

The untracked changes just a single directory itself, no file. The directory attributes changed? The diff command `git diff common/` show nothing

How did this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are in fact multiple untracked files within that directory.  Use `git status -uall` to show all of them.

Normally, `git status` collects them up and removes their names and shows just the directory-leading-to-them, so as not to print out too many names: it's pretty common to have a directory with several dozen or hundreds of untracked files if you forgot to list all such files in your `.gitignore`, and this makes the `git status` output too long.

Answer (score 2):

"Untracked files" refers to files that exist only in your working copy, and have no corresponding changes in the git repository. In other words, this directory is not *changed*, it's *newly created*.

In most cases, git doesn't actually care about directories - they're not tracked as items, and you can't commit an empty directory. However, a newly created directory might contain many files, and make the output of `git status` far too long, so the directory name is listed as a summary.

If you use `git add common`, all the files *currently* in that directory will be staged for inclusion in your next commit, and tracked from then on. If you add `common/` to your `.gitignore` file, the entire directory will be excluded from future `git status` checks.